# Capture video from specific frame opencv

Tags: opencv, frames

i have problem with capturing video from specific frame. Even if code is very simple. It works like the image is all noised and only the moving object are clear. And it works for me, but only for like 3-4 seconds, after i get crash. Some screen shots:
Errors plus noised and clear part of image - i.stack.imgur.com/wIh9p.png
Errors - i.stack.imgur.com/5xFHy.png

And here is my code:

```
int main(int, char**)
{
    namedWindow("edges",1);
    cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT);
    cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES,50);
    cap.read(frame);
    resize(frame,frame,Size(1920/2,1080/2));
    imshow("edges",frame);
    for(;;)
    {
        cap.read(frame);
        resize(frame,frame, Size(1920/2,1080/2));
        imshow("edges",frame);
        if(waitKey(1) >= 0) break;
    }
    waitKey();
    return 0; //return
}
```

Is there anyone could help me?

Comment: DO you stream from IP camera? What is the exact address for streaming? Also did you try to use suffix "?tcp" at the end of your address? This should avoid noisy cubes. Example: rtsp://name:password@ipaddress:port/media.amp?tcp

Comment: Where is your cap declaration/definition ? How do you instantiate it ? Also you don't need to cap.read,resize,imshow outside the loop if you do it in the loop anyway

Comment: Well, im not streaming any video, just loaded it from file. I didnt past here whole code, but here is this line:
VideoCapture cap("wideo.wmv");
Just simple video capture.
Also, i think i need to resize window each time, if i dont i get an error ;) But, its not a problem anyway. I just cant handle with puting video to the specific frame :/

Comment: found out problem is only on my computer, same code on the other act well. anyone know the answer?